# Using the 'webpage' Phantom module in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, rendering, phantomjs

I am trying to wrap a PhantomJS script in a node.js process. The phantom script grabs a url from the arguments provided on the command line and outputs a pdf (much similar to the rasterize.js example included with the pahntom install).

The phantom script I have works fine, it's just my employer wants a node script if possible. No problem, I can use the [node-phantom](https://github.com/alexscheelmeyer/) node module to wrap it.

But now I've hit a stumbling block, my phantom script has:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
```

So, node.js is trying to find a module called 'webpage', the 'webpage' module is built into the phantom install so node can't find it. As far as I can tell, there is no npm module called 'webpage'.

'webpage' is used like this:

```
page.open(address, function (status) {

    if (status !== 'success') {

        // --- Error opening the webpage ---
        console.log('Unable to load the address!');

    } else {

        // --- Keep Looping Until Render Completes ---
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            page.render(output);
            phantom.exit();
        }, 200);
    }
});
```

where address is the url specified on the command line and output is another argument, the name and type of the file.

Can anyone help me out? This is quite an abstract one so I'm not expecting much if I'm honest, worth a try though.

Thanks.

EDIT - Approx 2hrs later

I now have this which throws out a PDF:

```
var phanty = require('node-phantom');

var system = require('system');

phanty.create(function(err,phantom) {

    //var page = require('webpage').create();

    var address;
    var output;
    var size;

    if (system.args.length < 4 || system.args.length > 6) {

        // --- Bad Input ---

        console.log('Wrong usage, you need to specify the BLAH BLAH BLAH');
        phantom.exit(1);

    } else {

        phantom.createPage(function(err,page){

            // --- Set Variables, Web Address, Output ---
            address = system.args[2];
            output = system.args[3];
            page.viewportSize = { width: 600, height: 600 };


            // --- Set Variables, Web Address ---
            if (system.args.length > 4 && system.args[3].substr(-4) === ".pdf") {

                // --- PDF Specific ---
                size = system.args[4].split('*');
                page.paperSize = size.length === 2 ? { width: size[0], height: size[1], margin: '0px' }
                                                   : { format: system.args[4], orientation: 'portrait', margin: '1cm' };
            }

            // --- Zoom Factor (Should Never Be Set) ---
            if (system.args.length > 5) {
                page.zoomFactor = system.args[5];
            } else {
                page.zoomFactor = 1;
            }

            //----------------------------------------------------

            page.open(address ,function(err,status){

                if (status !== 'success') {

                    // --- Error opening the webpage ---
                    console.log('Unable to load the address!');

                } else {

                    // --- Keep Looping Until Render Completes ---
                    process.nextTick(function () {
                        page.render(output);
                        phantom.exit();
                    }, 200);
                }

            });

        });
    }
});
```

But! It's not the right size! The page object created using the phantom 'webpage' create() function looks like this before it's passed the URL:

[image: phantom returned page]

Whereas mine in my node script, looks like this:

[image: my page]

Is it possible to hard code the properties to achieve A4 formatting? What properties am I missing?

I'm so close!

Comment: You get anywhere with this Adam? I'm curious.

Comment: Unfortunately not in the end. I persuaded my team to use the phantom process instead which worked fine.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what tool is that being used in the last two screenshots?

Comment: It's called Power JSON Editor for Mac. It's on the Mac App Store. Well worth what I paid for it. It can be a pain editing sometimes but generally good.

Answer (score 14):

It should be something like:

```
var phantom=require('../node-phantom');
phantom.create(function(error,ph){
  ph.createPage(function(err,page){
    page.open(url ,function(err,status){
      // do something
    });
  });
});
```

Your confusion here is because you want to reuse the same concepts and metaphors from your PhantomJS script. It does not work that way. I suggest that you spend some time studying the included tests of node-phantom, see https://github.com/alexscheelmeyer/node-phantom/tree/master/test.

Comment: thanks for the answer. can't believe the creator of Phantom answered :) . I'm so so close to nailing this. I'm getting a PDF output now, but it's not the right size (A4). I need to use the decorateNewPage(opts, page) function exported as create() from 'webpage' instead of  ph.createPage(function(err,page) because 'webpage' receives all of the settings and stores them in the page var. Is this possible?

Comment: Check my update to the question, i'm very close but can't crack it

Answer (score 6):

Using https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node I have made an A4 page in nodejs using phantom with the following code:

```
phantom.create(function(ph){
    ph.createPage(function(page) {
        page.set("paperSize", { format: "A4", orientation: 'portrait', margin: '1cm' });
        page.open("http://www.google.com", function(status) {
            page.render("google.pdf", function(){
                console.log("page rendered");
                ph.exit();
            })
        })
    })

});
```

Side Note:

the page.set() function takes any variable that you would set in the rasterize.js example. See how paperSize is set above and compare it to the relevant lines in rasterize.js

Comment: How to work this out with [`phantomjs-prebuilt`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantomjs) ?

Comment: @Rayon Check out this module I ended up making https://github.com/rknell/url2pdf I was used very recently in production for a big project and has been pretty solid, just stay away from the direct HTML to PDF conversion if you are using images