# Phantomjs can't open filename

Tags: coffeescript, screenshot, phantomjs

I'm writing a bit of coffeescript with phantomjs to take screenshots of multiple urls. Every time I try running it though, I get an error message, `Can't open <filename>`. What gives? Here's my code:

```
  page = require('webpage').create()

  page.viewportSize =
    width: 1024
    height: 760

  urls = phantom.args
  i = 1
  for url in urls
    do (url) ->
      output = "screenshot-#{i}.png"
      page.open url, (status) ->
        if status isnt 'success'
          console.log "Error opening url \"#{page.reason_url}\": #{page.reason}"
          phantom.exit(1)
        else
          console.log "Page opened.."
          window.setTimeout (->
            page.clipRect =
              top: 0
              left: 0
              width: 1024
              height: 760
            page.render(output)
          ), 200
      i += 1

  phantom.exit()
```

I tried commenting bits out and it seems that the part that's failing is the page.open(url). Oddly the error message says the file itself can't be opened.

Comment: Have you tried appending "http://google.com" as the first url? Maybe the error message is valid.

Comment: Yes I tried inputting a string directly and it hasn't seemed to work :(

Comment: try hardcoding? like `urls = ['http://google.com']`

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either. I've boiled it down to the bare minimum with just a simple `page.open 'http://www.google.com', (status)-> console.log "--->#{status}"` but I get the same error `Can't open 'test.js.coffee'` I'm starting to think there's omething broken with phantomjs's open method.

Comment: I think it boils down to this piece of code not working: `page.open('http://github.com/', (status)->
      console.log("Status: #{status}")
      page.render('github.png')
)`

Comment: Have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12957239/using-the-webpage-phantom-module-in-node-js that may help. Personally, I'm using Casper with Phantom for page testing, that might be a better way to go.

Answer (score 0):

*(As a quick aside: I think there is a cut-and-paste error in line 14. I believe you want `#{url}` in place of `#{page.reason_url}`.)*

I see two issues here, or one issue manifest in a couple of ways.

The `page.open` method is asynchronous -- that's why it accepts a callback function (your `(status)->...` stuff).

That's causing two types of problem for your code:

1. Your `phantom.exit()` call on line 28 is outside of the scope of the `for` loop (that starts on line 9) and of the callback method (that starts on line 12).

   Because the `open` call is asynchronous, when `urls` is `['http://google.com']`, the `for` loop will call `page.open('http://google.com/')` and then jump to `phantom.exit()` BEFORE the page has finished loading or the callback is invoked.

   You need to defer your `phantom.exit()` call until the `page.render(output)` method is complete.   Moving `phantom.exit()` right after -- and at the same of indentation as -- `page.render(output)` will make your program work for a *single* URL.
2. Even with `phantom.exit` inside the callback, you'll still have a problem when more than one URL is passed to your program.  Again, because `page.open` is asynchronous, you're effectively calling `page.open` several times in quick succession (and then exiting before all of those pages have loaded).

   Moreover, like a regular, single, web-browser tab, Phantom's `page` object can't really open multiple pages at a time.

To fix your program need to ensure that (a) one URL has been loaded and `rendered` before moving on to the next one, and (b) that you don't call `phantom.exit()` until all of the URLs have been rendered.

There are a few ways to go about this (google for "nodejs asynchronous for loop" or something like that), but depending upon your needs, it may be easier to just render one page per invocation of the program.

Here's a version of your program, updated for PhantomJS 2 and set up to render exactly one URL:

```coffee
system = require('system')
page = require('webpage').create()

page.viewportSize =
  width: 1024
  height: 760

url = system.args[2]
output = "screenshot-#{Date.now()}.png"
page.open url, (status) ->
  if status isnt 'success'
    console.error "Error opening url \"#{url}\": #{page.reason}"
    phantom.exit(1)
  else
    console.log "Page opened..."
    window.setTimeout (->
      page.clipRect =
        top: 0
        left: 0
        width: 1024
        height: 760
      page.render(output)
      console.log "Page rendered..."
      phantom.exit()
    ), 200
```

Since Phantom no longer parses CoffeeScript directly, to run this you'll need to first "compile" to JavaScript, like so:

```bash
coffee -c foo.coffee
phantomjs foo.js "http://www.google.com/"
```

This seems to work properly for me.